# Interesting CSS puzzle: should opacity of parent affect opacity of child, which is positioned absolutely, but NOT relative to parent

Tags: css, standards

Here's the test case:
https://jsbin.com/gerujabope/1/edit?html,css,output

Should `.test` be transparent (affected) or not?

Note: current state:

- Chrome, FF (latest): **transparent**
- IE11: **opaque**

Would be great if experts can point out what standards say.

**Update**: opened IE bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/2116899

Comment: Seems as a bug of IE11. Doesn't matter if position is relative in the parent or not, the childs inherits the opacity to all childs, doesn't depends of the position if absolute, relative or static.

Comment: Transparency is supposed to affect the parent and all children contained, regardless of the positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should indeed be transparent, since you are adding opacity to the whole DIV element.

If you only want the bgcolor of the DIV to be transparent, then you can use RGBA in the background property, so the child DIV won´t inherit it.